# What is the Lie algebra of the Euclidean group?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to find the Lie algebra for $E(n) = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0^t \\
\mathbf{x} & A
\end{bmatrix}: A \in SO(n), \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{E}^n \right\}$. In particular, I would like to show that $\mathfrak{e}(n) = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0^t \\ \mathbf{b} & B \end{bmatrix}:B \in \mathfrak{so}(n),\mathbf{b} \in  \mathbb{E}^n \right\}$ using only the definition that a Lie algebra is the tangent space at the identity of the Lie group.

I've managed to show that $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ is the set of skew-symmetric matrices but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show that every matrix of that form is in the Lie Algebra?

Comment: Yes, I think I can show inclusion in that direction but I relied on the matrix exponential map. I would rather do so without the map as the text I'm using has yet to introduce it, suggesting that there is another way without relying on such machinery.

Comment: There's definitely a quick way to show inclusion in that direction without the exponential map. I'm not sure how to get the reverse inclusion without a suitable theorem, though

Comment: What is the theorem you're thinking of for the reverse inclusion?

Comment: I don't know any of the names and I don't care to flip through my textbooks, but something to the effect of "if $M$ is an element of the Lie Algebra, then $\exp(tM)$ must be a one parameter subgroup of the Lie Group".  That way, we can *exclude* certain elements from the Lie Algebra.

Comment: Never mind, didn't need anything like that.

Comment: To be precise you are inquiring about the Special Euclidean Group, not the Euclidean Group per se.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Proof:** suppose that $\gamma(t)$ is a path in the Lie Group with $\gamma(0) = I$.  $\gamma$ must have the form
$$
\gamma(t) = \pmatrix{1&0\\ \mathbf x(t) & A(t)}
$$
It follows that $\gamma'(0)$ has the form
$$
\gamma'(0) = \pmatrix{0&0\\ \mathbf x'(t) & A'(0)} 
$$
which is of the desired form.

On the other hand, take any $B \in so$ and $\mathbf b \in \Bbb R^n$.  We can define $A(t)$ in $SO$ such that $A(0) = I$ and $A'(0)=B$, and define
$$
\gamma(t) = \pmatrix{
1 & 0\\ t\mathbf b & A(t)
} \implies 
\gamma'(0) = 
\pmatrix{
0&0\\\mathbf b & B
}
$$
thus, we have both inclusions and the sets are equal.

Comment: If $A'(0) = I$, how come, in the last line, the lower right block is $B$?

Comment: Sorry, mistake. See my latest edit.

Comment: Thanks for the help and answer!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom For the converse direction, how do you prove that $\gamma(t)$ is the exponential of $(b,B)$ for all $t$? I initially thought you were implying that $\gamma(t)$ is a one-parameter subgroup, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Andrew $\gamma$ is not a one parameter subgroup, it's an arbitrary differentiable path.